# RequireJS and Bower dependencies

Tags: build, requirejs, build-automation, bower, r.js

I'm Using Bower to install dependencies and using RequireJS's r.js.
But when using r.js to build, all of the bower-components are also included (tests, docs, non-minized js etc). As it's nice to have tests included with each components in my dev directory, I find it a hassle to deal with when using r.js.

How would I setup a app.build.js file for r.js, that only includes the needed dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option `skipDirOptimize` which should do what you want.

Comment: this is not ideal if using the `dir` property to optimize an entire project and wanting to keep dynamic loading, as it prevents `r.js` from minifying files, essentially achieving the same results as copying the source directory to the build directory.